# error: incompatible types: SearchFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

this code was working perfectly when i was using navigation drawer activity after making some changes to my project and start using bottom navigation activity it just wont work and give my the error of incompatible types .. i tried every possible answer related to this issue but i get the same error

---

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private TextView mTextMessage;

 SearchFragment searchFragment;
private FrameLayout Eframe;
private HomeFragment homeFragment;

private BottomNavigationView eNav;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Eframe = findViewById(R.id.main_frame);

    searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
```

> ```
> setFragment(searchFragment);
> ```

```
    eNav = findViewById(R.id.Nav);


    eNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.Search:
        >            setFragment(searchFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.Home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.Profile:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;

                case R.id.Notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
                case R.id.Menu:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });



    }




private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

instead of **extends AppCompatActivity** 
write **extends Fragment**.